# Building two associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

How can I create an object with two associations in rails. Say you have a Link model that belongs_to a User and a Subreddit, so how could you set the `user_id` and the `subreddit_id` when creating that instance of a link.

So far doing something like `@link = current_user.links.build(link_params)` will set the `user_id` but I'm not sure how to set the `subreddit_id` at the same time. Ideally I'd like to do both at the same time and avoid adding `subreddit_id` to `link_params` for security reasons.

Comment: What security reasons prevent you from adding subreddit_id to link_params?

Comment: I'm unclear on where you are getting the `subreddit_id` from if not from the params? If it's not being passed in with the params, where is it coming from?

Comment: @eirikir I could be mistaken but I feel like opening allowing it to be edited through the web is a bad idea. I'm not sure if it actually is though, I was under the impression it's best to be as restrictive as possible when it comes to that, but please correct me if I'm wrong on that

Comment: @DonalNoye You're very much correct there: its good to be as cautious as possible about what happens to data coming from the open web. You could also add something to the hash *not* from the web, e.g. `current_user.links.build link_params.merge(subreddit: @subreddit)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set them like so:

```
@link = Link.new(link_params)
@link.user = current_user
@link.subreddit = **some_subreddit**
@link.save
```